# Fake select field for Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm using Simple Form, and I have a few fields that are not associated with my model. I found using this fake field option to be a good solution:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Create-a-fake-input-that-does-NOT-read-attributes

I thought this was cleaner than adding an `attr_accessor` value for my fields, and it works great for text input fields. I'm hoping to accomplish the same thing with a Select Field.

I found this thread, but I couldn't find anything else:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/747

Has anyone found a similar option for a Fake Select Input? Thanks!

Comment: Its difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Perhaps you want to have a select box for some kind of association or nested attributes?  If so, check out Cocoon: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you'll use that "fake select" for UI purposes (probably as a mean to modify the form fields to present the user using Javascript?) and you don't want to deal with the value in the controller, you could just use [`select_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) with any field name, instead of the `simple_form` `f.input`. The value will be sent to the server, but it will be outside the model params, so you can just ignore it in the controller.

If I misunderstood your question, please clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If your just trying to get the `name='whatever'` instead of having `name='model[whatever]'` I've found it easiest to just specify the name attribute in `input_html { name: 'whatever', id: 'whatever' }` hash which over rides the default `model[attribute]`.

Otherwise you could create a `fake_select_input.rb` which would be similar to `fake_input.rb` but obviously use a select_tag instead and do something like `as: :fake_select`